# eventListner to add a text boxes when another text box gets focus (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, focus, addeventlistener

I'm  trying  to add  an eventListner to all the text boxes. When a box gets focus - a new box should be created.

I'd appreciate if you could help me deubg this code, cause it doesnt work...

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("focus",addTextBox,true);
}

function addTextBox(){  
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.setAttribute("type","text");
    this.appendChild(newInput);
}
```

Comment: What is `this` in your `this.appendChild(newInput)`?  It looks as though it will be another textbox.  You can't append one text-box to another.

Answer (score 0):

I think so too, your code as such is working - if you inspect the DOM you'll see that the new input field was created and appended to the original input field as child. But as my previous speaker mentioned, you cant set an input field as the child of an input field. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: ok - so I think you've already solved it :) - otherwise, you can add the new inputfields with this.parentNode.appendChild(newInput); (if there's a parent element, container, form, anything....) - but the EventHandler will in this case only be attached to the one you intially created - not the new ones.

Comment: Why will the event  handler won't be attached to the new ones? Do I need to make it run again after every time a new one is created?